# Is Visual Basic Application part of Microsoft Access?

Tags: ms-access

Is visual basic application (VBA) part of Microsoft Access?

Do VB and VBA use the same syntax?  To verify, Microsoft Access uses VBA not VB right?

If I create an access database using vba, can I run it on any computer that has Microsoft Access installed?

Thanks

Comment: A little background information always helps. Skim through [Wikipedia: Visual Basic for Applications](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visual_Basic_for_Applications) (one generally doesn't "create" an access database with VBA, but one might use VBA *in* an MS Access document)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Ofcourse VBA is strictly Microsoft Windows so if you run on any computer running Microsoft Windows it should work. And bytheway for the first question VBA IS is the same as VB.

And next time just mind the way you formulate your questions as your questions should be - i did this,this what i have, but no working - kinada questions check the https://stackoverflow.com/faq

Comment: "any computer running microsoft" is meaningless. "microsoft" is a corporation, and computers don't run "microsoft". They might run `Microsoft Windows`. Office is available for the Mac, however, so Windows isn't applicable either.

Comment: For simplicity sake I said Microsoft, meaning the platform one should think of is Microsoft windows. Thx u

Comment: I didn't downvote, but it's wrong. :-) Unless you're the Microsoft CEO, you don't "run Microsoft". Windows is the name of the operating system, and Office is the name of the Microsoft product line that VBA works within. (This is a technical site, and accuracy is important here.)

Comment: I note that Ken White, and I  am very sorry for this offense. Thank you that you did not down vote.

Comment: VBA runs on Macs as well. Saying that it is "strictly Microsoft Windows" is incorrect. VBA is not the same as VB. It has also been implemented in Non-Office apps including AutoCAD and WordPerfect.

Comment: @HeadofCatering: I mentioned that Office runs on Macs in my first comment here as well.

Comment: @KenWhite, I see that now. I was commenting on the answer itself.

Answer (score 2):

Yes.  To be more specific it's part of Office.  You can run VBA in Excel and Word also...

For simplicity sake - Yes, they have similar syntax. It really is more closely tied to VB before it was VB.Net. VB.Net has diverged quite a bit now from VBA BUT you will find the basic syntax has similarities.

Here's a [bit of history](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visual_Basic_for_Applications) on it...

Yes, if you create an Access DB that is using VBA in it, it should run on a computer with Access installed.